# sequelize and react won't connect postgresql without an error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a react app with express server. It's not working on one of my pc(others are fine exact same versions and setup). Problem is even though i can connect to my postgresql db both from terminal and pgadmin interface, neither express server or sequelize can't find/connect it and they don't produce any error. `sequelize db:migrate` finishes without an error or additional migration/table created message. This leads infinite loading on app but all pending requests eventually fail.

Here is my sequelize config file:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "database": "db",
    "host": "localhost",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "port": 5432
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "database": "db",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "port": 5432
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "database": "db",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "port": 5432
  }
}
```

and react config in .env and express server

**.env**

```
DB_PASSWORD=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=postgres
```

**server.js**

```
const connectionString = `postgresql://${process.env.DB_USER}:${
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD
}@${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_DATABASE}`;
```

`sudo systemctl status postgresql.service` returns this:

```
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-06-04 20:47:20 +03; 9min ago
    Process: 38637 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGROOT}/data (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 38640 (postgres)
      Tasks: 14 (limit: 19096)
     Memory: 123.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service
             ├─38640 /usr/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgres/data
             ├─38644 postgres: checkpointer
             ├─38645 postgres: background writer
             ├─38646 postgres: walwriter
             ├─38647 postgres: autovacuum launcher
             ├─38648 postgres: stats collector
             ├─38649 postgres: logical replication launcher
             ├─38662 postgres: postgres db ::1(42040) idle
             ├─38834 postgres: postgres db1 ::1(42242) idle
             ├─38899 postgres: postgres db2 ::1(42352) idle
             ├─38912 postgres: postgres db3 ::1(42378) idle
             ├─38949 postgres: postgres db4 ::1(42450) idle
             ├─38960 postgres: postgres db5 ::1(42470) idle
             └─38971 postgres: postgres db6 ::1(42492) idle

Jun 04 20:47:20 archPC postgres[38640]: 2020-06-04 20:47:20.535 +03 [38640] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.3 on x8>
Jun 04 20:47:20 archPC postgres[38640]: 2020-06-04 20:47:20.536 +03 [38640] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1>
Jun 04 20:47:20 archPC postgres[38640]: 2020-06-04 20:47:20.536 +03 [38640] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127>
Jun 04 20:47:20 archPC postgres[38640]: 2020-06-04 20:47:20.541 +03 [38640] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/run>
Jun 04 20:47:20 archPC postgres[38643]: 2020-06-04 20:47:20.565 +03 [38643] LOG:  database system was shut down >
Jun 04 20:47:20 archPC postgres[38640]: 2020-06-04 20:47:20.573 +03 [38640] LOG:  database system is ready to ac>
Jun 04 20:47:20 archPC systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL database server.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been trying to fix this issue and finally found a solution.

If you are using Node v14 just like me, you need to update pg module from npm and that's all